# Como exibir o CPF em vários lugares diferentes a cada X segundos na tela do vídeo usando HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Alguém tem alguma ideia ou sugestão de como fazer o CPF ficar rodando a cada X segundos na tela do vídeo utilizando HTML5?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Você pode criar uma div com position relative/absoluto e jogar encima do video, colocar video como z-index -1 e a div do cpf com z-index maior que -1 aí ele vai sobrepor o video com o cpf.

Comment: pode ser sobre o vídeo, portanto gostaria que o CPF ficasse piscando a cada X segundos em vários lugares diferentes na tela do vídeo durante a reprodução.

Answer (score 1):

Bem lá vamos nós, eu achei bem diferente a sua pergunta, e até agora também não entendi qual a utilidade de se ficar passando o CPF na frente de algum vídeo, de qualquer forma o processo é simples e segue o que os colegas já disseram nos cometários.

Eis meus código simples *(pense em uma versão 0.0.0.1)*, como você não especificou se estava usando algum Framework como JQuery fiz com JavaScript puro, mas adaptar para outro não é difícil, pelo contrario.

**CSS**
Bem conforme os colegas já indicaram você deve dividir seus elementos em duas camadas, no meu caso atribui um ID a tag de <video> e disse que ela fica embaixo *(z-index: -1)* de todos os elementos junto a ela atribui outro ID na tag <div> que contem o texto do CPF fica em cima *(z-index: 3;)* além de dizer que ela tem uma posição absoluta na tela ou seja ela não ficara presa aos elementos que estão a sua volta, o resto é firula como cor, fundo e bordas, coloquei isso para visualizar o elemento se mexer na tela.

```
<style>
#seuVideo { z-index -1px; border: 1px solid #000000; }
#seuCPF { width: 150px; height: 20px; z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #FF0000; }
</style>
```

**HTML**
O HTML é a parte mais simples do código eu misturei tags de HTML5 no caso a de vídeo com tags de HTML4 como a div, quebra de linha e aliamento central, além de css inlinha *(para esconder o texto e so mostrar na hora certa)*, estava com preguiça de criar tudo bonitinho já que para nosso exemplo assim mesmo serve, eu tentei centralizar o vídeo, porque dentro do JavaScript existe uma *"jogada"* para ele saber se localizar dentro do HTML então fiz isso de proposito.

```
<br><br>
<center>
 <video width="320" height="240" id="seuVideo" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
 <div id="seuCPF" style="display: none;">XXX.XXXX.XX-XX</div>
</center>
```

**JavaScript**
Agora chegamos a alma da coisa toda, o JavaScript, bem temos 3 processos no JavaScript que descrevo com mais detalhes abaixo:

- Saber se o vídeo esta 'tocando' ou não
- Calcular a posição do vídeo e o tamanho do texto
- Fazer o "loop" de posições aleatórias do texto

Assim sendo tentarei explicar melhor dentro do próprio código:

```
<script>
// Define o tempo para cada aparição do texto (no caso meio segundo)
var seg = 500;
// Faz a leitura de todas as propriedades do elemento <video> 
var video = document.getElementById("seuVideo");
// Faz a leitura de todas as propriedades do elemento <div> 
var texto = document.getElementById("seuCPF");
// Variável usada para controle do "loop"
var time = null;

// Função que pega a posição (X/Y) de qualquer elemento na tela
// Bastando informar seu respectivo ID
function Posicao(elemento) {
 var xP = 0;
 var yP = 0;

 while (elemento) {
  xP += (elemento.offsetLeft - elemento.scrollLeft + elemento.clientLeft);
  yP += (elemento.offsetTop - elemento.scrollTop + elemento.clientTop);
  elemento =elemento.offsetParent;
 }

 return { x: xP, y: yP };
}

// Função que gera um número aleatório entre um intervalo
function PosicaoAleatoria(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// Função que sorteia número aleatórios de acordo com o tempo definido
// Além de posicionar o texto nessa posição  
function RandTexto(wMin, wMax, hMin, hMax) {
 var rX = PosicaoAleatoria(wMin, wMax);
 var rY = PosicaoAleatoria(hMin, hMax);

 texto.style.left = (rX + "px");
 texto.style.top = (rY + "px");

 time = window.setTimeout("javascript:RandTexto(" + wMin + "," + wMax + "," + hMin + "," + hMax + ");", seg);
}

// "Ouve" se o video está sendo executado
video.addEventListener("play", function(e) { 
 // Pega a posição da "caixa do vídeo" na tela
 var videoPos = Posicao(video);

 // Captura o tamanho do vídeo
 var vWidth = video.videoWidth;
 var vHeight = video.videoHeight;

 // Pega o tamanho da caixa de texto
 texto.style.display = "";
 var tWidth = texto.clientWidth;
 var tHeight = texto.clientHeight;

 // Calcula o local onde é possível apresentar o texto
 var rWidth = ((videoPos.x + vWidth) - tWidth);
 var rHeight = ((videoPos.y + vHeight) - tHeight);

 // Inicia o "loop" para criar o piscar o pisca
 RandTexto(videoPos.x, rWidth, videoPos.y, rHeight);
});

// "Ouve" se o vídeo foi pausado e limpa os eventos
video.addEventListener("pause", function(e) {
 window.clearInterval(time);
 texto.style.display = "none";
});
</script>
```

Basta salvar como "video.html" e abrir para testar, eu testei usando o Chorme, Firefox e IE e pelo menos para mim funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela força, funcionou exatamente da forma que eu queria.   vlw

Comment: Só um problema, quando ativa o fullscreen do vídeo o CPF não aparece na tela :/ Alterei o CSS da div do vídeo #seuVideo { 
    z-index: -1;
} para #seuVideo { 
    z-index: -100;
} porém não funcinou

Comment: @Wandes Cardoso de Souza; Bem não sei se isso é possível, já que quando você abre em Fullscreen o navegador entra em outro "status" então toda página fica pra atrás dele. Nesse caso teria que colocar o CPF dentro do vídeo mesmo através de edição.